# How can I rename how my Arduino UNO (or any other Arduino) shows up on the computer?

Tags: arduino-uno

I need to rename my Arduino UNO in a way that when it connects to the computer then it reads not as "Arduino" in device manager but as "My instrument name". I need to know how to do this on an UNO and Pro micro specifically but also on other arduinos. Please also suggest if there are other development boards available where names is not preprogrammed but programmable. Thank you.

Comment: For the Pro Micro, have you tried something like [this](https://www.shellhacks.com/arduino-change-devices-vid-pid-name/) (found by googling for "Arduino change PID")? For the Uno you would need to reflash the Atmega32u4 chip, that is responsible for the USB communication. Thats a bit more hacky, but there are tutorials for that online.

Comment: If "the computer" is a Linux computer you can create UDEV rules.  For example, you may, based on which USB port you plug your Arduino into, control most aspects of the USB connection.  In this way  you wouldn't have to change the PID or VID of the Arduino.  But the question should then be posted in a [Linux stackexchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).